# Does RequestPolicy support wildcards?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm using [RequestPolicy](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/requestpolicy/) in Firefox and I'd like to whitelist all the domains of the form of xxx.cloudfront.net.

A quick search with google seem to indicate that it should support wildcards; I tried to manually whitelist `*.cloudfront.net`, but it doesn't work.

Is it because of the revision ? I'm using 0.5.28 which should be the latest (as it appears from the linked web page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcard are supported by RequestPolicy, but only on version 1, which is currently in Beta.

Installing the beta version from [here](https://www.requestpolicy.com/channels.html)  solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If **Base domain** is selected in RequestPolicy **Options** > **General**, you can then include `cloudfront.net` in RequestPolicy **Options** > **Whitelist:**  **Destinations** to get the wildcard whitelist effect for the [domain + subdomains](https://www.requestpolicy.com/faq.html#faq-third-party-sites).

[RequestPolicy](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=1051805)

Comment: I tried this too, but it doesn't work.